# How can I enable multi-cursor occurrence highlight for multiple files in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

In VS Code, I can press `Ctrl+D`, multiple times, with a word selected inside a file and it will select all the occurrences of that same word in a **multi-cursor** fashion, which is great.

Now, I want to do the same, but over **multiple files**. If I use the "search" tool in the left menu, I can easily select all the occurrences where I would like to change, over multiple files. There is a "Replace with" option, but my case is not just replacing text with the same text. I would need to copy something from each line and place it again on the same line -- as you can easily do with multi-cursor selection.

**So I would like to combine both things: multi-cursor selection, but among multiple files.** So a *multi-file-multi-cursor selection*, lets say.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> but my case is not just replacing text with the same text. I would need to copy something from each line and place it again on the same line -- as you can easily do with multi-cursor selection.

Note that regex find and replace in the Search View is a thing. You can use regex grouping. Ex. If you want to replace `<ignore> <some-alphas> <some-nums> <ignore>` with `<some-nums> <some-alphas>`, you could turn on regex mode, search for `([a-zA-Z]+) ([0-9]+)` and then put `$2 $1` in the replace field, adjust the search details like include files / exclude files patthers, dismiss any finer-grained matches you don't want to touch, and then replace all.

---

As for the thing with occurrence selection, VS Code 1.85 just added multi-document occurrence highlighting: https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_84#_multidocument-highlighting (just visual highlighting and not actual text selection / cursor creation) (see the setting `"editor.occurrencesHighlight": "multiFile"` (previously `editor.multiDocumentOccurrencesHighlight` which defaults to `false`) in v1.85). So it doesn't seem like a big stretch for them to also implement actual text selection of occurrences across documents / editors. If you'd like for that to be a thing, I'd suggest to [raise an issue ticket](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/new?assignees=&labels=&projects=&template=feature_request.md).

Comment: If anyone reading this ends up raising an issue ticket like I suggested, please either comment here with the link to the issue ticket, or notify me in the issue ticket with "@starball5" and a link to this Stack Overflow post so I can update it.